# Printing All Values Geneterated by a Model in R

Tags: r, statistics

After running a function in R testing the fit of a model to data, e.g.:

`> (lm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy))`

one can use `summary()` (or `summary.aov()`, `summary.glm()`, etc.) to have `R` print a subset of the values generated when running that function:

`> summary(lm1)`

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML ['lmerMod']  
Formula: Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject)  
   Data: sleepstudy

REML criterion at convergence: 1743.6

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.9536 -0.4634  0.0231  0.4634  5.1793 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev. Corr
 Subject  (Intercept) 612.09   24.740       
          Days         35.07    5.922   0.07
 Residual             654.94   25.592       
Number of obs: 180, groups:  Subject, 18

Fixed effects:
            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  251.405      6.825  36.838
Days          10.467      1.546   6.771

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
     (Intr)
Days -0.138
```

How can I have R print a list of *all* of the values generated by a model along with their labels? (So that here I could see all of the values that went into generated these results.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run a model (e.g., `lm1`), you can see the categories of things it computes using names (eg, `names(lm1)`, then grab the values using `$`.

```
# Dummy Example
df <- data.frame(v1 = 1:10,
           v2 = runif(10))

lm1 <- lm(v1 ~ v2, data=df)

# See all types of computed values
names(lm1)

# grab computed values
lm1$coefficients
lm1$residuals
lm1$fitted.values

# some things stored in lm1 are your inputs, such as model
lm1$model
```

UPDATE: for lme4, grab items using `@` instead of `$`. You can also see other computed items using `names(summary(lm1))`, then grab items off `summary()` using `$`

```
library(lme4) 
df <- data.frame(v1 = 1:10,
                 v2 = runif(10),
                 v3 = c(1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4))

lm1 <- lmer(v1 ~ v2 + (1 | v3),  data=df)

lm1@devcomp

names(summary(lm1))
summary(lm1)$sigma
```

Comment: Thank you for you prompt response; I'm sorry I added my example after you added yours. I'm indeed using `lme4`. When I run a model (`lm1`) and get output similar to what I posted in my question (after your response), and then run `names(lm1)`, R returns `NULL`. Any idea why?

Comment: Ah I see - yep I get `NULL` too after using `lme4`. I think instead of grabbing the values using `$`, you'll use `@` for `lme4`. So it'd be `lm1@` then you should see a drop down with different items to use. Here, not sure how to print a list of everything you can grab using `@`, but you can at least see options via the drop down.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you yet again @Rob Marty. Using `@` indeed does allow me to access the values that are "under the hood". For posterity's sake, it may be worth noting that subsumed under the fields accessible first with `@`, e.g., `lm1@devcomp`, there are additional values then accessible with `$` calls: `lm1@devcomp$dlms`.

Comment: You need `slotNames` to list slots of an S4 object.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see an overview of all of the components of an object in R, `str` is really helpful. It also handles S3 (e.g. from `lm`) objects and slots for S4 objects (e.g. from `lme4`) appropriately.